# How to enforce that a field/property represents a certain type of physical quantity?

Tags: c#

In certain types of code (e.g. simulation/ games/ optimization), many physical quantities/properties are stored, manipulated, and exposed for objects (position, velocity, distance, area, volume, time, time-differences). In these types of code, all these quantities are typically represented by floating point numbers, i.e. doubles in c#.

This allows you to add times to distances, area's to volumes, times to times, and positions to positions.

But you *never* want to do this. You will only want to add time-differences to times, distances to other distances or positions, and multiply areas with distances. Still, errors are easily made, especially when working on code by someone else.

There are many options to mitigate this danger. You could define custom classes representing various physical quantities, and subsequently forbidding certain types of interactions programmatically. Or you adhere to strict naming conventions (e.g. delay_timedifference). Which of those two options is best under what (if any) circumstances? How to implement the first option? How to do the naming for the second option?

Comment: The relatively 'easiest' way would be to check the [F# units of measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) for needed calculations and then possibly interop with C#, I don't know any easy way to do it in C# only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, the second option is used, but more for convenience.  Naming becomes a matter of making it obvious what you're dealing with, ie: naming properties `Area` and `Volume`, but even then, there is a unit issue.

You can handle the first case by making an entire set of custom classes (or immutable struct types) to handle each of the different combinations, which can work well, but can make the code quite a bit more cumbersome to work with.  The `DateTime` struct in the framework is a good example - at its core, it's basically just a long integer value, but it's wrapped into a struct to prevent its usage as anything but a moment in time.

Note that other languages have options for this - for example, F# allows [Units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) to be handled at a language level, but this isn't supported in any way in C#.

Comment: Just to add: F#'s units are not exported to the generated assemblies, so the only way to use this feature is to keep all the relevant code in F#.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Yeah, which is why I really said "not supported in any way in C#" - it's great if you stay completely within the F# realm, but useless as soon as you try to interop :(

Comment: Also worth pointing out that you can use operator overloading to intelligently return relevant types.  In a physics library, you can overload operators so that eg. dividing a Displacement1D by Time returns a Velocity1D, Displacement2D by Time returns Velocity2D, Displacement3D by Time returns Velocity3D, dividing VelocityXD by Time returns AccelerationXD, multiplying that by Mass returns Force etc.  That can be a very useful way of adding extra double checks into the calculations you are doing in some systems.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would make most sense to implement them as structures, not classes as they are value types.  You'd want to do operator overloading to ensure that appropriate operators are available against other structures of the same type and appropriate different types.  You probably also want to overload the ToString function to output the scalar value, possibly with units.

You can also create generic structures for creating vectors of other structures - these can be 2 dimensional (x and y properties), 3 dimensional (x,y and z properties) or N dimensional (an array of values).  These structures can also have appropriate operator overloading to perform vector calculations.  If you do it correctly, it will be a very natural way of interacting with the data.

Comment: I agree with structs on this, and overloading the operations. This, then allows for scenarios like jleahy described, where you could multiply a Velocity by a Timespan and get a Distance, for example. The biggest benefit of this is compile time type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the two options you've described are workable, but they have downsides. The first option results in too many classes (and then you need to define a lot of relationships) and the second one can be error prone.

A better option could be to create one custom class which both encapsulates a floating point number as well as a list of units and their multiplicities. For example 1 meter per second may become {n=1, types={length:1, time:-1}}. You can then enforce that no numbers may be compared, added or subtracted unless their units are the same. Multiplication and division would add the multiplicities of matching types together.

eg.

```
1 m/s * 4 seconds = 4 meters
{n=1, types={length:1, time:-1}} * {n=4, types={time:1}} = {n=4, types={length:1,time:0}}
```